# Htaccess clean urls code not working as I want

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

So here's what my htaccess clean url code look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^myvar=0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /$1.php?myvar=0 [QSA,L]
```

This htaccess code permits files on the root to work with .php, trailing slash, or nothing. So blah.com/blah.php works blah.com/blah works blah.com/blah/ works

However if there's a folder on my root, say the name is 'news', the file 'news' on the root cannot take on a clean url. So blah.com/news.php works but blah.com/news and blah.com/news/ both do not work.

For some reason, files inside a folder must have a file extension (.php), so blah.com/news/obama.php works blah.com/news/obama and blah.com/news/obama/ both do not work.

What's wrong with the .htaccess code and how can I correct it?

tl;dr Is there an htaccess code that can make it so .php works, trailing slash works, and no trailing slash works? I know absolutely nothing about htaccess.

Also: I posted this same question yesterday but was met with no reply. Not sure why. If there is something confusing, I'll try to clear it up. Thanks!

Comment: posted same question yesterday? guilty as charged.

Comment: Yeah, as I admitted. I didn't get a response. What other options do I have =/

Comment: pray, cry, scream or google it. one of them should be deleted AFAIK based on SO's rules

Comment: have you checked your webserver log files? there's probably something about news.php.php not being found

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?=\.php/?)?$ /$1.php?myvar=0 [QSA,L]
```

could help. Your log files are really golden in this case.